# Paginate GCP logadmin entries

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm following [this GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/logging/latest/logadmin#pagination) on how to paginate the entries fetched by the `logadmin` client (`cloud.google.com/go/logging/logadmin`). Below you can see the relevant part of the code:

```golang
        nextTok, err := iterator.NewPager(it, 5, r.URL.Query().Get("pageToken")).NextPage(&entries)
        if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("problem getting the next page: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
        }
```

However, when I use the provided token to fetch the next page in a different HTTP request, I get an error like follows
`problem getting the next page: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = page_token doesn't match arguments from the request`.
Having said that, if I try to fetch the next page in the same process (for example, through a `for` loop), it works like a charm.

```
for {
    nextTok, err = iterator.NewPager(it, 10, nextTok).NextPage(&partialEntries)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("problem getting the next page: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    entries = append(entries, partialEntries...)

    if nextTok == "" {
        break
    }
}
```

Do you know how can I paginate the results through different HTTP requests?